# Position divs with dynamic widths horizontally relative to one another

Tags: html, css, position

I'm creating an app using Angular JS that will have dynamic content. How can I use CSS to position a variable number of `div`s with dynamic widths horizontally relative to one another?

To be more specific here's a diagram:

[image]

These three `div`s are inside of another `div` (in grey) with `overflow-x: scroll` and `overflow-y:hidden`. At the moment the `div`s are positioned with `float: left`, but when I resize the window to make the grey `div` smaller, the green `div` will disappear as it jumps below the two other ones.

I'd rather have the green `div` stay in line and have the grey `div`'s scroll-bar account for it. I already tried `white-space: nowrap` Is there any way to do this?

Code can be [viewed here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFDn7BMQNbS5NJvkKGJB?p=preview).

```css
root {
 display: block;
}

.cardPanel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 125px;
 bottom: 75px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 background-color: #BFBFBF;
}

.cardPanelDiv {
 float: left;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 white-space:nowrap;
}

.cardDividerDiv {
 float: left;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 75px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}

.cardDivider {
 position: abolute;
 margin-left: 10px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 5px;
 background-color: #808080;
}

.cardDividerWords {
 position: abolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cardPanel">
  <div class="cardDividerDiv" style="background-color: yellow">This is a div</div>
  <div class="cardPanelDiv" style="background-color: red">More div things I just love. I just noticed that I randomly picked the colours of stoplights for this.</div>
  <div class="cardPanelDiv" style="background-color: green">Just more oh so nice div. It is just so lovely to look at because this one is GREEN!</div>
  <div class="cardPanelDiv" style="background-color: blue">Here's another div that jumps down to the next line. It shouldn't jump. It should just scroll.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't help you if we can't see your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I didn't do the greatest job explaining the question. Anyway, I [figured out](http://plnkr.co/edit/30TbL1ErFTx586NmAyMs?p=preview) how to do it:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  bottom: 75px;
  background-color: #808080;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container .panel-outer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.container .panel-inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-outer" style="background-color:yellow">
    <div class="panel-inner" />adsfasdfasdfasdfassdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfadsfdf
  </div>
  <div class="panel-outer" style="background-color:green">
    <div class="panel-inner" />jdklf;uoijdhksjkasdfjksasldkfjasdlfkasd;fksdsdf
  </div>

  <div class="panel-outer" style="background-color:blue">
    <div class="panel-inner" />adsfasdfasdfasdfassdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfadsfdf
  </div>
  <div class="panel-outer" style="background-color:red">
    <div class="panel-inner" />adsfasdfasdfasdfassdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfadsfdf
  </div>
  <div class="panel-outer" style="background-color:cyan">
    <div class="panel-inner" />adsfasdfasdfasdfassdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfadsfdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see here :http://plnkr.co/edit/6TdWj7Oe5IuDN0ewF4Ro?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="grey">
   <div class="yellow"></div>
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>
   </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.grey {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  height: 100%;
}
.yellow {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
.red {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.green {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the width of my divs to be based on the content inside of them, not percentage values.

Comment: you can set max-with only like here http://plnkr.co/edit/uV4znKlPUi9AazNBa3x4?p=preview otherwise div with content excising with of parent content will be always dropped down